# GeoDjango - how to save GMap marker's coordinates into model

Tags: django, google-maps, gis, postgis, geodjango

models.py:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=u"Location", default=u'')
    coords = gis_models.PointField(u"lng/lat", srid=4326, blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py:

```
class AddLocationPageView(CreateView):
    model = Location
    form_class = LocationForm
    template_name = 'add_location.html'
```

forms.py:

```
class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ['name']       # there is no 'coords'
```

add_location.html:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}

            <div id="map-add-location" ></div>       # place for GMap

            <div>
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <button type="submit">Add</button>
            </div>
</form>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var mapOptions = ...
    map = new google.maps.Map($('#map-add-location')[0], mapOptions);

    map.addListener('click', function(e){
            placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
            var position = marker.getPosition();
            var lat_input = $('<input type="hidden" name="lat"/>');
            var lng_input = $('<input type="hidden" name="lng"/>');
            $(lat_input).insertBefore($('#id_name'));
            $(lng_input).insertBefore($('#id_name'));
            $(lat_input).val(position.lat());
            $(lng_input).val(position.lng());
    });

    var marker;
    function placeMarker(latLng, map) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
        });
        return marker
    }

});
```

I am confused. I do not understand what I should do further.
Please, help.. how can I save the lat and lng values in the 'coords' field of Location model ?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Your question is not very clear. For example why do you have a form? If you are only grabbing the location from a marker shown on the map, why is a form needed?

Comment: ok.. in this case could you explain the most fit approach from your point of vew? I mean how I should get coords in my model..

Comment: How can I do that without really understanding what you are trying to do? The presence of your form is confusing. Do you expect the user to input the name field?

Comment: yes.. the point is that user puts marker at map then enters some name (there are other fields in model and in form respectively but I took off them for brevity) and pushes button Add. And I need to save in my db this instance with name and coords. Thanks!